# Induction Principle as described in van Dalen’s Logic and Structure

Tags: logic

(First and foremost I’m sorry if the question is trivial. I’m reading the book on my own.)

Theorem 2.1.3 in van Dalen’s Logic and Structure (5th edition) states the following:

Let $A$ be a property, then $A(φ)$ holds for all $φ ∈ \text{PROP}$ if

1. $A(p_i)$, for all $i$, and $A(⟂)$,
2. $A(φ), A(ψ) ⇒ A((φ □ ψ))$,
3. $A(φ) ⇒ A((¬φ))$.

The author hasn’t defined what he means by the notation $A(φ)$. I suspect the meaning is twofold: either ‘the property $A$ of $φ$’ or ‘the property $A$ of $φ$ holds’, depending on the context. Am I correct? Do I interpret the theorem in plain English as follows?

Let $A$ be a property, then the property $A$ of $φ$ holds for all $φ ∈ \text{PROP}$ if

1. the property $A$ of any atomic proposition holds,
2. if the property $A$ of $φ$ and that of $ψ$ hold, then the property $A$ of $(φ □ ψ)$ holds (for any connective $□$),
3. if the property $A$ of $φ$ holds, then the property $A$ of $(¬φ)$ holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'The property $A$ of $\varphi$ holds' makes it sound as if $\varphi$ already has property $\varphi$ before you even ask whether or not it holds ... so this sounds a bit weird to me.

I would translate $A(\varphi)$ as ' $\varphi$ has property $A$'

Comment: I see. So you’re saying that $A(φ)$ on its own (without a verb) means ‘$φ$ has property $A$’, while $A(φ)$ with a verb means ‘the property $A$ of $φ$’ (as a subject). Is that right? Now the two meanings are basically the same thing, with one as a noun phrase, and the other as a full sentence.

Comment: @Taiki Well, in order for the induction principle to make sense as it is stated, $A(\varphi)$ needs to be a claim. 'the property $A$ of $\varphi$' is not claim. But '$\varphi$ has property $A$ is a claim. So it's the latter you want.

Comment: Indeed! My question is basically how to read $A(φ)$ as a claim. I thought maybe I had to add ‘hold’, but in fact all I need to do is interpreting it as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: @Taiki I suppose you could say 'the claim that $\varphi$ has property $A$ holds true' .... but that would be rather redundant, yes.